# Correct implementation of k-means?

Tags: python, k-means

I am trying to apply the k-means algorithm to group the data from a csv file.

My code looks like this:

```
kmeans=KMeans(n_clusters=6).fit(np.genfromtxt('file.csv', delimiter=' '))
```

The `kmeans.labels_` returns this:

```
[[  8.62068966e-03   3.44827586e-02   8.62068966e-03 ...,   9.75781955e-18
    9.75781955e-18   2.15517241e-03]
 [  1.06837607e-03   1.60256410e-02   1.06837607e-03 ...,   1.06837607e-03
    2.13675214e-03   1.06837607e-03]
 [ -1.56125113e-17   1.14285714e-02   5.71428571e-03 ...,   1.43114687e-17
    1.90476190e-03   1.90476190e-03]
 [  3.49040140e-03   1.91972077e-02   3.49040140e-03 ...,   1.71303943e-17
    1.74520070e-03   1.74520070e-03]
 [  1.93050193e-02   4.63320463e-02  -2.94902991e-17 ...,   1.38777878e-17
    1.38777878e-17   1.38777878e-17]
 [  3.37837838e-03   1.68918919e-02   1.01351351e-02 ...,   1.35135135e-02
    3.37837838e-03   3.37837838e-03]]
```

I do not understand why it returns 6 floats in each group. Somebody can tell me what is this output? I read documentation but I did not find anything about this and how to understand it.

Thank you.

Comment: What's in the CSV ?

Comment: well there is potentially much more than 6 floats in the group. what does `kmeans.labels_.shape` return?